# Available Django apps listing?

Tags: django, django-apps

I'm learning django and I love the ease of plugging in a 3rd party app (like django-registration).  Is there a site listing available 3rd party Django apps?  I know I can search google code, github or bitbucket, but is there a more organized, django-specific resource out there?  Maybe with reviews or ratings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like:

- http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DjangoResources
- http://www.django-apps.com/
- http://djangosnippets.org/